# Kendo tabstrip not generating ID dynamically

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-tabstrip

Kendo tabstrip wraps a < li > tag that has ID attribute. In the official kendo website, the ID is a unique string - 'k-tabstrip-tab-' followed by a random alphanumeric string. for example. 'k-tabstrip-tab-jasdj656aSfJASDJH3'. But in my version of kendo it is not generating this random alphanumeric string but instead it is 'k-tabstrip-tab-' followed by a decimal number as shown in the image.

[image]

It might not seem like a big deal but we are using multiple tabstrip in the same page so it is generating duplicate IDs. Does anyone know why this is happening ??

Comment: What version of kendo are you using? E.g. `2024.1.130`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a known issue in the older version of kendo and has been addressed since kendo version 13.1.0

This is recorded in kendo version change log here:
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/changelogs/kendo-angular-ui/